# Android: How to find Navigation Bar location (Right or Left) when phone is in landscape mode?

Tags: android, android-orientation

Is there a way to identify the location of the navigation bar on the screen when phone is in landscape mode? I need to identify the location of the back button during landscape mode.

Comment: There may not *be* a BACK button in a navigation bar. Devices with gesture navigation set up will not have one. Multi-window devices (e.g., Chrome OS) will have BACK in a title bar. With split-screen, your window may not be adjacent to the navigation bar. And so on.